# Multiple web.xml database connections in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, database-connection, web.xml

I am not completely new to Java, but I have recently learned about using a web.xml file to connect to a database.

It would be convenient to connect to the mySql I already have set, and a MSSql database within the same maven project.

I have researched this topic a bit, and haven't really found the answer I am looking for.

It isn't really helpful in terms of the question, but I have provided my web.xml as a code base if you would like to show me how this would be done.

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>db.driver.class</param-name>
        <param-value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>db.url</param-name>
        <param-value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/lib-1323</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>db.username</param-name>
        <param-value>root</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>db.password</param-name>
        <param-value>admin</param-value>
    </context-param>



    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done. I would do some research on Spring and hibernate.

I found [this article which may help](http://www.200oksolutions.com/connect-multiple-databases-single-web-application-java/).

You would need the Microsoft SQL Dependency in your pom.xml, and the correct driver.

Hope this helps.